# Парсинг get запроса

Tags: массивы, javascript, синтаксический-анализ

Здравствуйте.
Я с джаваскрипт не сильно дружу, но хочу подружится.
набросал код парсинга get запроса, но он как-то не до конца работает. и проверить выходную информацию его работы я тоже не могу.

```
function pars2()  {
    var p_url2 = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var parametr2 = p_url2.split("&");

    var values= new Array();
    for (var a=0;  a < parametr2.length;  a++)  {
        var b = parametr2[a].split("=");
        values[b[0]]=unescape(b[1]);
        //alert (parametr2[a]);
        //alert (values[a][b]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        alert('параметр: ' + values[i][0] + '\n' +  'значение: ' + values[i][1] + '\n');
    }

}
```

[пример тут](http://jsfiddle.net/E8pea/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Всё уже давно придумано](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values) :)

Comment: чужой код хорошо, но что бы понять почему 2+2=4
Надо взять свои палочки и пораскладывать ;)
И выяснить, что 4, это и 0+4=4, и 3+1=4, и sqrt(16)=4

Comment: По ссылке, которую я привёл, вариантов для ознакомления побольше будет. Замечу: работающих вариантов. А тыкаться в кнопочки наугад и потом спрашивать "что здесь не так" - IMHO, не самый лучший вариант учиться :)

Comment: @I_Car а еще 4 это 8*sin(pi/6) и прочее вы хотели бы все варианты перебрать ?